# Cloning an instance of a class, but not exactly

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a class in Scala:

```
class Class123(val val1: Int, val val2: String, val val3: AnotherClass, val val4: AnotherClass2)

//I create Class123 somehow, it doesn't matter how exactly
val class123_1: Class123 = parseClass123()
```

And now I want to create another instance of `Class123` exactly the same as `class123_1` except the last parameter `val4`, I want it to be different:

```
val class123_2 = // the same as class123_1 but with different last parameter val4
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a case class and specifying the parameter to change by name.

```
val class123 = new Class123(...)
val copy = class123.copy(val4 = ...)
```

This was introduced in Scala 2.8, and there's [more info here](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/named_and_default_parameters_in_scala.html).

Comment: by the way, it not use a case class, is there any way to do that?

Comment: @MariusKavansky: You could define such method yourself. Case class provides you an autogenerated implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Turn class to the case class:

```
scala> case class Class123(val val1: Int, val val2: Int, val val3: Int, val val4: Int)
// defined class Class123

scala> val foo = Class123(1,2,3,4)
// foo: Class123 = Class123(1,2,3,4)

scala> val bar = foo.copy(val4 = -4)
// bar: Class123 = Class123(1,2,3,-4)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already method `copy` in all `case class`es.

You should just define your class as case class:

```
case class Class123(val1: Int, val2: String, val3: AnotherClass, val4: anotherClass2)

val c1: Class123 = ???
val c2 = c1.copy(val4 = newValue)
```

You could define such method yourself if you don't want to make your class a case class:

```
class Class123(val val1: Int, val val2: String, val val3: AnotherClass, val val4: anotherClass2) {
  def copy(val1: Int = val1, val2: String = val2, val3: AnotherClass = val3, val4: anotherClass2 = val4) =
    new Class123(val1, val2, val3, val4)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jay Conrod describes [here](http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/32/) a `copyWith` method, based on reflection, suitable for "non case classes" as well. You can use his trait as a mixin for any class.